# How to set the privacy of a Facebook post in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to set the [privacy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/) of a Facebook post in iOS. This setting lets you specify whether you want the post to be seen by everyone, your friends, or only you. Before I added the audience setting, everything worked. After I added it, the code crashed with this error on the FBRequestConnection line:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is the relevant code. I debugged and made sure all the parameters passed to Facebook were not nil and reasonable. I'm not sure if it is a Facebook problem or an Objectice-C issue.

```
- (void)postMessage:(NSString *)message url:(NSURL *)url thumbnail:(NSURL *)thumbnail audience:(SocialNetworkAudience)audience
{        
    NSString* privacy;
    switch (audience) {
        case SocialNetworkAudiencePrivate:
            privacy = @"SELF";
            break;
        case SocialNetworkAudienceProtected:
            privacy = @"ALL_FRIENDS";
            break;
        case SocialNetworkAudiencePublic:
            privacy = @"EVERYONE";
            break;
    }

    [FBRequestConnection
        startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
        parameters:@{
            @"description": message,
            @"link": url.absoluteString,
            @"picture": thumbnail.absoluteString,
            @"privacy": @{
                @"value": privacy
            }
        }
        HTTPMethod:@"POST"
        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried a bunch of random stuff and found out that the privacy parameter should have been a string. From reverse engineering, I believe that Facebook checks the length of each parameter before sending out the request. Too bad Facebook never documented this.

Example:

```
@"privacy": @"{'value': 'SELF'}"
```

Comment: This worked for me but be careful there seems to be a hierarchy in the value options: `everyone > friends of friends > friends > only me` (not sure where custom comes). This way the privacy setting from the time user granted privileges to the app overwrites your `value` (e.g. when app is granted privileges with default `only me` value, irrespective of what you send from the app will always be overwritten to `only me`).